# How can I parse a filename into components

Tags: regex, macos, bash

I have a collection of vhs transferred television episodes all of which are titled according to the format "Show Name SXXEYY Episode Title.mp4" and I would like to add iTunes mp4 tags to them. I have a way of doing this tagging from the command line but would like to improve my shell scripting capabilities and write something that can do it automatically.

I figured that a bash script would do this for me. Ideally, a properly written regex would look at the filename and return Show, Season, Episode, and Title and allow me to pass these results to my tagging tool in the bash script. A properly written regex would return BASH_REMATCH[1]..[4] with these four pieces of data.

Here's where I'm stuck - I can't seem to get my regex sequences to behave.

My understanding of the syntax suggests to me that expressions such as:

```
Regex for Show Name: ^(?:(?! S[0-9][0-9]).)*
Regex for Season Number: (?<=S)(.*)(?=E)
Regex for Episode Number: (?<=S[0-9][0-9]E)..
Regex for Episode Title: (?<=S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9] )(.*)(?=.(mp4))
```

should yield acceptable results. But so far, I can't even get bash to return any arguments. I'm clearly missing something, but

```
#!/bin.bash

for filename in "Cop Rock S01E03 Happy Mudder's Day.mp4" ; do
    if [[ "$filename" =~ (?<=S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9] )(.*)(?=.(mp4)) ]]; then
        echo  "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
done
```

should return an episode name and the mp4 suffix, but so far the results have not been forthcoming.

I'm open to other solutions as well, such using sed, but I have never used sed before and can barely spell it, so the learning curve is likely to be steep.

I would be most grateful if someone could point out the error that I'm making. It's bash 3.2; the =~ operator does work.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to use Perl-style regular expressions (specifically, the zero-width lookbehind assertion), which `bash` does not understand. Try the following:

```
regex="(.*) S([0-9]{2})E([0-9]{2}) (.*)\.mp4"
for filename in "Cop Rock S01E03 Happy Mudder's Day.mp4" ; do
    if [[ "$filename" =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo "Show: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo "Season: ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        echo "Episode: ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        echo "Title: ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: `[0-9]` would be more concise.

Comment: Yeah. Not sure why I changed to `[[:digit:]]` when I wrote this regex. It accommodates other locales, but that's not really an issue here.

Comment: Yep, that solves it. Thanks! The children of my village shall sing of you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 1.5 year since the last activity on this question but I was looking for the same thing and came around this answer. I tweaked the answer a bit to be more generic (allow for all lowercase filename, dot's in stead of spaces, different extensions and multiple filenames) so I would like to share my update with you:

```
#!/bin/bash

regex="(.*)[ .][sS]([0-9]{2})[eE]([0-9]{2})[ .](.*)\.(mp4|mkv)"
for filename in ${*}
do
    if [[ "${filename}" =~ ${regex} ]]; then
        echo "Show: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo "Season: ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        echo "Episode: ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        echo "Title: ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    fi
done
```

If you copy this into a shell file and make it executable, you can use it more generically.